# How to inherit class WizardResourceImportPage?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to create a 'new project' wizard for my application. The first page of this wizard is simply the instance of org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewProjectCreationPage. I want to import some system files to current project in the second wizard page. I found that org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardResourceImportPage is quite close to my thougts, but I can't figour out how to inherit this class and produce a simple file import page.

Can anyone offer an example of doing this? Thanks!

I also tried to test it like below (overrided getFileProvider too), but the file tree shows only the checkbox but no filename.

```
protected ITreeContentProvider getFolderProvider()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new WorkbenchContentProvider()
  {
    public Object[] getChildren( Object o )
    {
      if ( o instanceof java.io.File )
        return FileSystemStructureProvider.INSTANCE.getChildren( o ).toArray();
      else
        return new Object[]{new java.io.File("C:\\temp")};
    }

    public boolean hasChildren( Object o )
    {
      if ( o instanceof java.io.File )
        return FileSystemStructureProvider.INSTANCE.isFolder( o );
      else
        return false;
    }

  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WizardResourceImportPage` is abstract, you can extend it and implement the three abstract methods. I'd have a look at `WizardFileSystemResourceImportPage1` which is working implementation of `WizardResourceImportPage` and either study that code or copy and paste source from that class to my own.

---

**Edit**

You're example from above only shows blank labels because `WizardResourceImportPage` uses a `WorkbenchLabelProvider` and this label provider will return `""` if the 'content' object (`File` in your case) is not adaptable.

Look at the `createFileSelectionGroup` method. Maybe it's enough to implement your own `LabelProvider` for `File` objects and call `selectionGroup.setTreeProviders(ITreeContentProvider, ILabelProvider)` to make it work with `File` items in the tree. The standard implementions seems to work with (eclipse) file resources only.

Comment: Thank you, but I think WizardFileSystemResourceImportPage1 is a little bit too complex and uses some internal classes which I can't use directly. I prefer a simple one.

Comment: Whenever I invoke selectionGroup's method, eclipse says this: Discouraged access: The method setRoot(Object) from the type ResourceTreeAndListGroup is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.6.0.I20100601-0800.jar

Comment: Yes, that's the general problem with those internal classes. That's why I usually copy code from internal classes into my own project...